# Xcode (Swift) error - use of undeclared type 'CustomCell'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cell

I've been learning table views from tutorials on YouTube. I was following every step told in the video, and did everything the same as the author of this tutorial, but for some reason I got a strange error - I've heard that it's about old version of Xcode used in the tutorial - I'm working on the latest one.

Debugger tells that "CustomCell" is undeclared.

Every help will be appreciated!

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOfCwiczenia.count

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CustomCell


    let person = arrayOfCwiczenia[indexPath.row]
cell.setCell(cwiczenia.nazwa, imageName: cwiczenia.obrazek)
    return cell


}
```

Comment: have you tried shift + command + K  to clean and then try to build again ?

Answer (score 1):

CustomCell looks to be a subclass of UITableViewCell

Looks like they left out the part where you need to create it

Create a new file called CustomCell and make sure it's base class is UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

You must have a file where you define the behaviour of the custom cell - if that's not called 'CustomCell' then it won't be declared.

Just make sure that you have the same name when you define the class and when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at [Apple's walkthrough](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html) on how to implement a table view. It has step by step instructions with pictures. If you scroll down the the *Design Custom Table Cells* section I think you will be able to see how to link the custom cell to a file properly

Answer (score 0):

Your tutorial should have mentioned all the details, but here it goes...

1. You need to define a subclass of `UITableViewCell` named `CustomCell`:

   import UIKit
   class CustomCell: UITableViewCell 
   {
       // Your custom properties/methods.outlets/etc.
   }

*(typically, in a source file named **CustomCell.swift**, but this is not compulsory)*

2. **If you are using a storyboard,** you need to set the class of your prototype cells to "CustomCell" in the **identity inspector** (third tab from the left on the right inspector pane - the one with the icon that looks like a newspapaer):

[image]

3. Also, In the **attributes inspector** (fourth tab from the right, icon looks like a slider), set the cell's identifier (in the case of your code, "Cell"):

[image]

3. **If you are not using a storyboard,** you need instead to register the custom cell class and identifier programmatically:

   ```
   func viewDidLoad()
   {
       tableView.registerClass(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
       // other setup...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error. Tried cleaning and building which worked but the main issue seemed to just be saving the CustomCell which then becomes recognised by the compiler and removes the error.

Its not limited to cells I've had it with other custom classes before as well. Good one to know about though!